# SELECT statement by looking at certain character of numeric value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

First post here. Please go easy.   :)

In my Oracle database, I have a table named `fun_table`. It contains one single column named `FIRSTCOLUMN`. This column contains only six digit numeric-only values. Here are the rows in `fun_table` currently:

```
FIRSTCOLUMN
-----------
201502
201503
201601
```

I want to write a SELECT statement from fun_table where only values whose sixth digit are NOT '1'. And since the data each subsequent year will follow this formatting (201602, 201603, 201701, etc., etc.) I don't believe that I wish to simply *ignore* values whose sixth character is '1'.

Does this make sense? Is this possible as a SELECT statement in SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: Nope, doesn't really make sense. You want all months except January?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The sixth digit in these values does not correspond to months 1-12 of the year, no. They repeat in that simple format each year though; every year, we'll see a repetition of that sixth value being 1, 2, and 3. So next year at this time, we'll see data of:

201502,201503,201601,201602,201603,201701

Is this at all helpful?

Comment: Try `select firstcolumn from table where to_char(firstcolumn) like '%1';`.

Comment: If it's numeric then you can just use a modulo 10 operation. Isn't that `MOD(firstcolumn, 10) <> 1` on Oracle?

Comment: Your firstcolumn looks like date. You can convert these numbers to date, then separate your date to year and month or you can use Extract, then select all where month > 1. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of confusing me a bit but here goes:

> I want to write a SELECT statement from fun_table where only values whose sixth digit are NOT '1'.

Example DDL/DML:

```
create table fun_table (FIRSTCOLUMN INTEGER);
INSERT INTO FUN_TABLE (FIRSTCOLUMN) VALUES (201502);
INSERT INTO FUN_TABLE (FIRSTCOLUMN) VALUES (201503);
INSERT INTO FUN_TABLE (FIRSTCOLUMN) VALUES (201601);
COMMIT;
```

Example query:

```
select *
from fun_table
where substr(firstcolumn,6) <> '1'
;
```

**Note**: you could use either `'1'` or `1` there but using `1` would use implicit typecasting.
Output:

```
201502
201503
```

Now as for this part:

> I don't believe that I wish to simply ignore values whose sixth character is '1'.

I don't really know what you mean there. If you elaborate I'll expand on my answer.

Comment: mmmmmpie, that is it! That is the output I wanted - to only output 201502 and 201503. 

You can ignore the last part of my original question. That was probably unnecessary to even mention.

I'm sure this was very simple for you, but this has helped me immensely. Now to make sure it applies to the rest of my task.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstcolumn FROM fun_table WHERE MOD(firstcolumn, 10) <> 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this also, shawnt00.